# Configure Postini and emailreg.org

Tags: email, whitelist, spam

One of our companies uses Postini services as our spam filtering service.  Unfortunately, the company has been tagged as a spammer and we're trying to use emailreg.org to whitelist us.  Emailreg.org wants us to add a CNAME which points to their domain (emaireg.org), while Postini has us add MX records (such as domainname.s7a1.psmtp.com.  Here are my questions:
1. Can adding Emaireg's CNAME cause either Postini to not work or our emails to be lost?
2. Which is order of execution (do the email go to Postini and upon their return to EmailReg or is it the other way around)?
3. Is there anything of which I should be aware when using such a setup?

Thanks, in advance, for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they asking you to make a cname from your mail fqdn to them?  Don't do that, it'll break your email.  From some subdomain of that?  Sure, go ahead.

Are you sure you want to be paying $20 to some service that says in big bold letters "this won't get you off of any blacklists" ?